# How can I put this function into a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a react native codebase in which I import a component and use the same function twice but with slight differences. I would like to outsource it into a new component somehow. Any ideas?
It looks like this :

```
handleConfirmApplication = async () => {
    const checkVals =
        get('shiftInvite.account.accountName', this.props) === ONBOARDING_ACCOUNT
            ? omit('payRate', this.props.confirmationCheckValues)
            : this.props.confirmationCheckValues;
    if (Object.values(checkVals).every(val => val)) {
        this.props.onToggleConfirmPopUp();
        this.props.onToggleLoadingApply();
        try {
            await this.handleShiftInviteDecision('ACCEPT')();
        } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert('Error', parseError(e));
        } finally {
            this.props.onToggleLoadingApply();
        }
    } else {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Please confirm all shift requirements');
    }
};
```

And the second one is the following :

```
handleConfirmApplication = async () => {

    const checkVals =
        get('shift.account.accountName', this.props) === ONBOARDING_ACCOUNT
            ? omit('payRate', this.props.confirmationCheckValues)
            : this.props.confirmationCheckValues;
    if (Object.values(checkVals).every(val => val)) {
        this.props.onToggleConfirmPopUp();
        this.props.onToggleLoadingApply();
        try {
            const shiftId = this.props.shift.id;
            const {
                data: { updatedShifts },
            } = await this.props.updateMyApplication(shiftId, 'APPLY');
            this.setState({
                updatedShift: updatedShifts.find(({ id }) => id === shiftId),
            });
        } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert('Error', parseError(e));
        } finally {
            this.props.onToggleLoadingApply();
        }
    } else {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Please confirm all shift requirements');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an `if/else` statement in your `try/catch` and a ternary condition to create your string. Choosing between one or another should be done by passing a parameter to your function :

```
handleConfirmApplication = async (isInvite) => {
    const checkVals =
        get(`shift${isInvite ? 'Invite' : ''}.account.accountName`, this.props) === ONBOARDING_ACCOUNT
            ? omit('payRate', this.props.confirmationCheckValues)
            : this.props.confirmationCheckValues;
    if (Object.values(checkVals).every(val => val)) {
        this.props.onToggleConfirmPopUp();
        this.props.onToggleLoadingApply();
        try {
            if(isInvite){
                await this.handleShiftInviteDecision('ACCEPT')();
            }
            else{
                const shiftId = this.props.shift.id;
                const {
                    data: { updatedShifts },
                } = await this.props.updateMyApplication(shiftId, 'APPLY');
                this.setState({
                    updatedShift: updatedShifts.find(({ id }) => id === shiftId),
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert('Error', parseError(e));
        } finally {
            this.props.onToggleLoadingApply();
        }
    } else {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Please confirm all shift requirements');
    }
};
```

And calling it :

```
handleConfirmApplication(true)
```

Have I missed any other differences between your functions ?

---

To Use it in a reusable component :

```
handleConfirmApplication = async () => {
    const { isInvite } = this.props
    const checkVals =
```

And calling it :

```
<MyComponent isInvite={false} /> //Just switch it to true to get the other version
```

Comment: The ideea is I wanna put this into a new component or something like that so i can reuse it

Comment: Then you simply have to pass the `isInvite` as a prop to your component